# Issue with path to .so libraries

Tags: solaris, path

I have an issue with path to .so files. I have a server with two accounts user1 and user2.
There is wget program, that is installed to user1 and I need it from user2. 
When I run it from user2 I get an error:

```
/export/apps/user1/local/bin/wget http://....
ld.so.1: wget: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
```

I checked output of ldd util for user1 (application works as expected):

ldd /export/apps/user1/local/bin/wget

libiconv.so.2 =>         /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2

For user2:

**libiconv.so.2 =>         (file not found)**

I updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/sfw/lib:/export/apps/user1/local/lib:**/usr/local/lib**

But after it I have the same problem. How can I fix it? Please note that I don't have admin access to this server and it is better to avoid modification of system-wide config files and solve this issue using non-root permissions.

Comment: did you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after updating it?

Comment: Does user2 have permissions to see the .so file?

Comment: @Petter H thank you, I forgot about export after assigment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not just assign it.